# How to force a dictionary to be written with " " instead of ' '

Tags: python, dictionary

So I am working on a project in which I build an ongoing dictionary for kennings (its for a norse mythology course). The problem I run into is on occasion a kenning has an apostrophe in it. For example the kenning "wolf's joint" which has the definition "joint" gets written to the dictionary as {"wolf's wrist": 'joint'}, this would be fine if the json.loads() function didn't through up an error because the key has "" and the value has ''. I was wondering if there is a way to force a dict to be written always with the "" instead of ''.

Comment: Did you try `json.dumps`?

Comment: You are doing something wrong in the first place if you are writing the Python dict itself to disk.

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:syntax].

Comment: Dictionaries *don't have any single or double quotes*. What do you mean? Do you mean the string representation like when you `print` a dict? Because that should not matter. You seem to think that the string representation of Python objects can be parsed with `json.loads`, that is not true, and you need to be using the json serializer to write valid json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `json.dumps`:

```
>>> print(json.dumps({"wolf's wrist": 'joint'}))
{"wolf's wrist": "joint"}
```

Comment: I will try this thank you!

Comment: This worked perfectly...Thank you!